# how to control attached files access?

Tags: 7

I have a webform where users insert their informations, after that the manager consulted the submission, he change the workflow state of the submission to : submission approved or submission rejected, if it's approved, then the coordinator must add attached files, after that, the finance manager should be able to download the files then to validate the submission, in the end the user can see the attached files and be able to download them, but during the process user must not see the attached files. 

     It would be great if anyone give me an idea if there is a module can help me controlling attached files access. I'm using Drupal 7.
[image]

Comment: My first thought would be to set #access to FALSE while preprocessing the field - evaluate the node workflow state and set it to FALSE accordingly. That would prevent it from being seen until ready.

Comment: I' m using webform workflow module and webform module, could you please clear up for me, i honestly couldn't follow your suggestion